# Discord.py - Add role to user

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord import Embed, Color


def ex(args, message, client, invoke):
    if (message.mentions.__len__() > 0):
        for member in message.mentions:
            server = message.server.name
            role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="MMDev")
            yield from client.add_roles(member, role)
```

This is my code. I have tried to add the mentioned user the role "MMDev". 
This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 91, in on_message
    yield from commands.get(invoke).ex(args, message, client, invoke)
  File "cmdmute.py", line 9, in ex
    role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="MMDev")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

It´s Python 3.5

Comment: @Jakob.B please add your inputs also.

Comment: your `server` variable is a string, containing the name of the server, not a server object; you cannot just do `server.roles`; you can get the role by: `role = message.server.roles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.server.name` is the name of the server, you instead want the `Server` object itself.

```
def ex(args, message, client, invoke):
    if (message.mentions.__len__() > 0):
        for member in message.mentions:
            role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name="MMDev")
            if role:
                yield from client.add_roles(member, role)
```